# Create stack with unique random numbers fast

Tags: c#, random, generator

I created a method where I generate a stack of random unique numbers. The code works but I need this to run a lot faster. Does anyone have a suggestion.

Lower is the lowest number for the random number,
upper is the highest number for the random number
and count is the amount of numbers I need.

I tried searching around for a better solution, but I couldn't make it work.

```
    public static Stack<int> RandomNumbersGenerator(int lower, int upper, int count)
    {
        Stack<int> stack = new Stack<int>();
        Random rnd = new Random();
        while (count > 0)
        {
            int h = rnd.Next(lower, (upper + 1));
            if (!stack.Contains(h))
            {
                stack.Push(h);
                count--;
            }

        }
        return stack;
    }
```

Comment: If the range between `lower` and `upper` is small enough you could consider just generating all of the numbers between them, shuffling that array, then taking the first N values.

Comment: @RetiredNinja the range can vary wildly. from 5 numbers to a thousand numbers.

Comment: Lookups with the Contains method in a Stack<T> are O(n). This costs more and more the larger the stack grows. Particularly if you _don't_ get a lot of repeated random values (because if a value is not a repeat value then the whole stack has to be scanned linearily by the Contains method from the very first to the very last element in the stack). Thus, for a large amount of numbers i would suggest to use a collection type that automatically ensures uniqueness of its items (and allows for fast lookups), like HashSet, and only after generating all the numbers filling the stack from the HashSet

Comment: @MySkullCaveIsADarkPlace this indeed speeds things up greatly, thanks.

Comment: Please post a proper answer with your solution. It does not belong in the question (nor does "solved" belong in the title)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what my version would like like. Very similar to your final version but more compact and tests only one condition each time through the loop.

```
public static Stack<int> RandomNumberGenerator(int lower, int upper, int count)
{
    Random rnd = new();
    HashSet<int> set = new();

    while (set.Count < count)
        set.Add(rnd.Next(lower, upper + 1));

    return new Stack<int>(set);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are a couple reasons why something like this might be executing slowly. Firstly, [`Stack<T>.Contains(T)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.stack-1.contains?view=net-6.0#remarks) is a linear search. Which means every time you call that method, the entire stack is iterated from beginning to end (or until the matching element is found). If `count` is large, then the method might take a long time to execute simply because you're iterating the `Stack` so many times.

You might address this by building a [`HashSet<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=net-7.0) which should have much faster lookups... O(1) vs O(n).

```
public static Stack<int> RandomNumbersGenerator(int lower, int upper, int count)
{
    Random rng = new Random();

    // Initialize the HashSet with the count to avoid having to resize it while
    // building it.
    HashSet<int> items = new HashSet<int>(count);

    while (count > 0)
    {
        int next = rng.Next(lower, upper);
        // HashSet<T>.Add will return true if the item was added or false if it
        // was not because it already exists.
        if (items.Add(next))
        {
            count--;
        }
    }

    // Return a Stack<int> using the HashSet<int> to build it.
    return new Stack<int>(items);
}
```

This might run in to issues as well. Imagine a situation where `lower` is `0`, `upper` is `12345678` and `count` is `12345677`. In this case, you have to keep iterating until you randomly generate almost every number between `0` and `12345678`. In this case, you might be better off generating an `int[]` with every number between `lower` and `upper`, shuffling it, then taking `count` items to build the resulting `Stack<int>`.

```
public static Stack<int> GenerateRandomStack(int lower, int upper, int count)
{
    var rng = new Random();
    var numbers = new int[upper - lower];
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
    {
        numbers[i] = lower + i;
    }
    int n = numbers.Length;
    while (n > 1) 
    {
        int k = rng.Next(n--);
        int temp = numbers[n];
        numbers[n] = numbers[k];
        numbers[k] = temp;
    }
    return new Stack<int>(numbers.Take(count));
}
```

There are probably cases I haven't thought of where neither of these approaches work well.

Answer (score -3):

Will there only be one match for h that you want to add? If so, simply continue to the next iteration of your while loop after finding your match. Something like this:

```
if (!stack.Contains(h))
                {
                    stack.Push(h);
                    count--;
                    continue;
                }
```

Depending on how your data is set up this could speed it up quite a bit.

Comment: `continue` changes nothing about this code. There is no code after the `if` block to skip.

Comment: Incorrect, right from the Microsoft docs "The continue statement starts a new iteration of the closest enclosing iteration statement (that is, for, foreach, while, or do loop)" https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/jump-statements

Comment: Which is exactly what happens when the code executes naturally. There's no code after the ending brace in the conditional so it goes right back to the top of the loop.